# Kiln node - FAILED

Tags: node, kiln

I have an issue with setup node:

> Jan 07 18:13:15 rhei-ln systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ur7.png): Started Kiln. Jan 07 18:13:15
>   rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: umount: /oldroot: filesystem was
>   unmounted, but failed to update userspace mou Jan 07 18:13:15 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: ln: failed to create symbolic link
>   './backend': File exists Jan 07 18:13:15 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: ln: failed to create symbolic link
>   './frontend.jsexe.assets': File exists Jan 07 18:13:15 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: ln: failed to create symbolic link
>   './static.assets': File exists Jan 07 18:13:15 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: ln: failed to create symbolic link
>   './version': File exists Jan 07 18:13:17 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: NOTICE:  relation "NodeInternal_pid" already
>   exists, skipping Jan 07 18:13:17 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]:
>   NOTICE:  relation "ProcessLockUniqueId" already exists, skipping Jan
>   07 18:13:18 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: Migrating: ALTER TABLE
>   "ConnectedLedger" ALTER COLUMN "forceConnectivityCheck" Jan 07
>   18:13:18 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: Migrating: ALTER TABLE
>   "ConnectedLedger" ALTER COLUMN "forceConnectivityCheck" Jan 07
>   18:13:18 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: Migrating: ALTER TABLE
>   "MailServerConfig" ALTER COLUMN "enabled" SET DEFAULT T Jan 07
>   18:13:18 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: Migrating: ALTER TABLE
>   "MailServerConfig" ALTER COLUMN "enabled" TYPE Bool Jan 07 18:13:18
>   rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: 07-Jan-2020 18:13:18LevelError"""Node
>   Query failed for 'bakerRightsWorker' Rea Jan 07 18:13:18 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: no port specified, defaulting to port 8000 Jan
>   07 18:13:18 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: Listening on
>   http://0.0.0.0:8000 Jan 07 18:13:19 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]:
>   07-Jan-2020 18:13:18LevelError"""Node Query failed for 'bakerWorker'
>   Reason: N Jan 07 18:13:38 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: 07-Jan-2020
>   18:13:38LevelError""Websocket error:  CloseRequest 1001 "" Jan 07
>   18:14:11 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]: 07-Jan-2020
>   18:14:11LevelError"kiln-node"Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store Jan
>   07 18:14:11 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]:  Jan 07 18:14:11
>   rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]:  Jan 07 18:14:12 rhei-ln
>   run-kiln-backend[7886]: 07-Jan-2020
>   18:14:11LevelError"kiln-node"Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store Jan
>   07 18:14:12 rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]:  Jan 07 18:14:12
>   rhei-ln run-kiln-backend[7886]:

I was trying to execute `sudo chown -R kiln /var/lib/kiln` but does not help. Any ideas?

I use Mint Linux.

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT2:

[image]

Comment: There is a new version of Kiln available now, can you try with that after removing the existing Kiln using `sudo dpkg --purge kiln`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same, does not work, logs (Kiln 0.7.4):

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-10-28 21:51:15 CET, end at Thu 2020-01-09 15:13:54 CET. -- Nov 11 10:52:26 kiln-node[30691]: Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store/nz0nzcwxnhi50xyp4cbpxwk01q7xjrm1-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node ["upgrade","storage","--data-dir","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU"]
                                  <STDOUT>

                                  <STDERR> Nov 11 10:52:27 kiln-node[30691]: Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store/nz0nzcwxnhi50xyp4cbpxwk01q7xjrm1-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node ["config","show","--config-file","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/.tezos-node-config30691-0.json","--data-dir","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU"]
                                  <STDOUT>

                                  <STDERR>
-- Reboot -- Jan 09 15:11:43 kiln-node[14042]: Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store/jdzg5ha2y9pxzp96ylc4259j8yj6pg6v-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node ["upgrade","storage","--data-dir","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU"]
                                  <STDOUT>

                                  <STDERR> Jan 09 15:11:43 kiln-node[14042]: Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store/jdzg5ha2y9pxzp96ylc4259j8yj6pg6v-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node ["config","show","--config-file","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/.tezos-node-config14042-0.json","--data-dir","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU"]
                                  <STDOUT>

                                  <STDERR> Jan 09 15:13:48 kiln-node[14345]: Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store/jdzg5ha2y9pxzp96ylc4259j8yj6pg6v-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node ["upgrade","storage","--data-dir","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU"]
                                  <STDOUT>

                                  <STDERR> Jan 09 15:13:48 kiln-node[14345]: Command Failed : (stdout): /nix/store/jdzg5ha2y9pxzp96ylc4259j8yj6pg6v-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node ["config","show","--config-file","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/.tezos-node-config14345-0.json","--data-dir","/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU"]
                                  <STDOUT>

                                  <STDERR>
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `ls -l /var/lib/kiln/*`

Comment: also what is your username in the linux, ie the output of `whoami` command. I hope your username is not `kiln`

Comment: @dfordivam user name is: "panta", I updated the question according your suggestion.

Comment: So somehow the dir in the folder are all owned by user `panta`. Perhaps you can try the command again `sudo chown -R kiln /var/lib/kiln` and see if the output of `ls -l /var/lib/kiln/*` changes

Comment: Look at edit2 please, now the owner is "kiln". And still does not work.